# Make a particular variable's values appear in an R df column as a condition of the text in another column

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have a data frame with a column that contains text and a number of variables that contain values that correspond to the strength of that league. I want to create a new column in the same df that contains the corresponding variable value for each row.

I tried this:

```
prospects2020$leaguemod <- if(prospects2020$LEAGUE == "QMJHL") {
  QMJHLe
} else if (prospects2020$LEAGUE == "OHL") {
  OHLe
}else{
  WHLe
}
```

where `QMJHLe`, `OHLe` and `WHLe` are variables in my GE, and it creates the column but every value is equal to QMJHLe's value. I'm getting the error message:

Warning message:

```
In if (prospects2020$LEAGUE == "QMJHL") { : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I feel like this should work but I'm pretty new to this. Maybe this is a wrong-headed way to accomplish what I am trying to do? How can I make it behave as I designed, or should I be using an entirely different approach?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `QMJHLe`, `OHLe` and `WHLe` variables are of length 1, you can use `ifelse` here for vector values.

```
prospects2020$leaguemod  <- ifelse(prospects2020$LEAGUE == "QMJHL", QMJHLe, 
                              ifelse(prospects2020$LEAGUE == "OHL", OHLe, WHLe))
```

Or with `case_when` :

```
library(dplyr)
prospects2020 %>%
   mutate(leaguemod = case_when(LEAGUE == "QMJHL", ~ QMJHLe, 
                                LEAGUE == "OHL", ~OHLe, 
                                TRUE ~ WHLe))
```

Comment: ifelse seems to be working when nested as you laid out (I had like a dozen other leagues to add), but the case_when option came up with an error saying the input couldn't be logical.

Comment: It depends on what you have in your data, I am glad `ifelse` works for you.